# Rx.Net : Calling multiple IObservable in SelectMany

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

**Please Note:**  This is continuation of the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190596/rx-net-chaining-subscribers-alternative-approach) posted earlier but the solution of interest is of a different situation.

I am trying to make multiple calls to the methods that each return IObservable but the **values being returned back in the SelectMany statement is a Task and hence the following Subscribe statement does not compile**.

This is the code snippet

```
 var myWorkList = new List<MyWork>
                {
                    new MyWork(),// MyWork.Execute(data) returns IObservable
                    new MyWork()
                }.ToObservable();

 var results =
   myService
    .GetData(accountId)
    .SelectMany(data => myWorkList.ForEachAsync(r => r.Execute(data))
    .Subscribe(result =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Result Id: {result.Id}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Result Status: {result.Pass}");
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to use `.SelectMany`. Try this:

```
var myWorkList = new List<MyWork>()
{
    new MyWork(),
    new MyWork()
}.ToObservable();

var query =
    from data in myService.GetData(accountId)
    from myWork in myWorkList
    from result in myWork.Execute(data)
    select result;

var results =
    query
        .Subscribe(result =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Result Id: {result.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Result Status: {result.Pass}");
        });
```

Here's my testing code:

```
public static class myService
{
    public static IObservable<MyData> GetData(int x)
        => Observable.Return(new MyData());
}

public class MyWork
{
    public virtual IObservable<MyResult> Execute(MyData data)
    {
        return
            from isMatch in IsMatch(data)
            where isMatch
            select new MyResult() { Id = 1, Pass = true };
    }

    public IObservable<bool> IsMatch(MyData data)
    {
        return Observable.Return(true);
    }
}

public class MyResult
{
    public int Id;
    public bool Pass;
}

public class MyData { }
```

When I execute I get this:

```
Result Id: 1
Result Status: True
Result Id: 1
Result Status: True
```

---

In the comments on your previous question I suggested doing this as a list of delegates. Here's how:

```
var myWorkList = new Func<MyData, IObservable<MyResult>>[]
{
    md => new MyWork().Execute(md),
    md => new MyWork().Execute(md),
}.ToObservable();

var query =
    from data in myService.GetData(accountId)
    from myWork in myWorkList
    from result in myWork(data)
    select result;
```

You get the same result.

Comment: Thank you and this works as well.  Thank you for also providing the alternative as well.

Answer (score 1):

The list can be declared just as list of `MyWork`-s - using no `ToObservable` here.

```
var myWorkList = new List<MyWork>
            {
                new MyWork(),// MyWork.Execute(data) returns IObservable
                new MyWork()
            };
```

then, we map the objects, returned by `myService.GetData` onto the elements of `myWorkList` and take them as `IObservable`-s.

```
var observables = myService
         .GetData(accountId)
         .SelectMany(data => myWorkList.Select(r => r.Execute(data)));
```

And now you can observe them.

Either together - merged:

```
var subscription =
          observables
           .Merge()
           .Subscribe(result =>
           {
               ...
           });
```

Or separately:

```
var subscriptions=
          observables
           .Select(obs => 
               obs.Subscribe(result =>
               {
                   ...
               }))
           .ToArray();
```

Update: the latter case must be immediately materialized in order to prevent side effects (.ToArray()).

Comment: The "Or separately" option is terrible. Don't do `.Subscribe` in a `.Select` life that. That's horrible. Had you written the line `.SelectMany(data => myWorkList.Select(r => r.Execute(data)));` like `.SelectMany(data => myWorkList.SelectMany(r => r.Execute(data)));` you would have avoided the need for `.Merge` or any funky inner subscribes.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I updated my answer to make it safer. In the case of "Merge" you have the option to have only one subscription. In many cases it's a lot more usable than having many separate ones.

Comment: "In many cases"? In every case. Nested subscribes are terrible. And what do you mean by "the latter case must be immediately materialized in order to prevent side effects"?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it - the way I wrote it will work perfectly. I have an IEnumerable of IObservable-s which I convert to an array of subscriptions (IDisposables). Please, if you use words like "terrible" be so kind to explain what you exactly mean with it. First of all, semantically, and secondarily, syntactically.

Comment: @Enigmativity, .SelectMany(data => myWorkList.SelectMany(r => r.Execute(data))) does not work because the compiler cannot infer the types for SelectMany. 

But I do agree that SelectMany operates the same way as calling Select and Merge.

Comment: @GautamTGoudar - I just tested `.SelectMany(data => myWorkList.SelectMany(r => r.Execute(data)))` and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Enigmativity.  Yes it works.  For this I had to make myWorkList to be an Observable.
    
    var myWorkList = new List<MyWork>
            {
                new MyWork(),
                new MyWork()
            }.ToObservable();